# Show And hide grid on ribbon page click

Tags: c#, devexpress, ribbon-control, devexpress-wpf

I m trying to show grid control on ribbon page click . When clicking on different ribbon pages should show different grid . for this i m first trying to show and hide a grid on ribbon page click using Selected page event . It is not working fine an exception is coming.

My Code:

```
privatevoidRibbonControl_SelectedPageChanged(objectsender,RibbonPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        if (RibbonControl.SelectedPage == ribbonPageFolder)
    {
        grdFilingTest.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
        } 
        else if(RibbonControl.SelectedPage != ribbonPageFolder)
    {
        grdFilingTest.Visibility = Visibility.Hidden;
    }
    }
    catch(Exception ae)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(ae.Message);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You set the visibility of a Grid Control like this:

```
grdFilingTest.Visible = true; // makes the grid visible 

grdFilingTest.Visible = false; // hides the grid
```

Comment: Are you sure it's a grid control? I have tried the above code and it worked. May be your intellisense is not working. Try writing the code and check if it works.

Comment: Its devexpress (Grid Control ). Normally we take Data Grid But here i m talking of grid control .

Comment: Yes I am also using Dev Express Grid Control... The code that I wrote is working fine on my PC. However I could not find gridControl.Visibility, not even in the documentation. Did you try my code?

Comment: Please visit this link http://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/Question/Details/Q504304

Comment: u'll come to know that visibilty exists

Comment: Dude that not a Grid Control. C'mon read it yourself. 
That's DocumentPanelContacts.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;. There is a huge difference between Grid Control and DocumentPanelContacts

Comment: U said that visibilty attribute do not exists (not even in documentation) . I gave the link to have a look that it exists and if u still have any doubts give me ur email id i'll send u some screen shots that the same exists for GRID CONTROL

Comment: I meant that it does not exists for GridControl, You can recheck my comment. Yes I have doubts but I am not giving you my email address. However give me a link to the official documentation that shows GridControl.Visibility.

Comment: https://documentation.devexpress.com/#wpf/DevExpressXpfGridGridControlMembersTopicAll

Comment: My bad. I was checking on the windows forms, this is for WPF